# react-native unable to assign Production for NODE_ENV variable

Tags: node.js, react-native, environment-variables

I am trying to utilise the process.env.NODE_ENV to switch between the environments for my react native app, and am facing two issues here

**1. Assigning parameter to NODE_ENV doesn't seem to change the env value straight forward,**

executing the below command shows that it changed process.env.NODE_ENV value but doesnt seem to have changed the global.process.env.NODE_ENV

*execution command:*

```
NODE_ENV=development npm start -- --reset-cache
```

*output:* Please note, the second log statement still prints out development.

```
console.log("printing the changed value - ", process.env.NODE_ENV); // --> printing the changed value - production

console.log("checking the env content - ", process.env); // ---> checking the env content - { NODE_ENV: 'development' }
```

Workaround that i tried is to assign the process.env.NODE_ENV to the global instance,

```
global.process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV
```

Please do advise if this is a good approach to proceed with.

**2. Assigning "Production" as a value to NODE_ENV throws Attempted to Assign to read only property error,**

*Execution Command:*

```
NODE_ENV=production npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Please find image attached - 
[AssignToReadOnlyPropertyIssue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WZrG.png)

Answer (score 2):

The problem your facing here comes from an erroneous assumption:

`react-native` doesn't execute javascript in the same way as node.

Let's consider the following npm script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
}
```

When running `SOME_VAR="some value" npm start`, `process.env` will contain a entry for that environment variable, since it is running from the process where `SOME_VAR` was defined.

In `react-native` something different happens:
calling `npm start` starts the react-native packager which bundles your javascript code and then sends that javascript bundle to the installation in your emulator or device, where the bundle is in its turn executed. `react-native`'s packager doesn't "forward" the environment variables defined where the javascript was bundled.

---

Hopefully there are packages that aid us to be able to keep using the same patterns we're used to using when developing node apps.

One I found really helpful was [`babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables). This is a babel plugin that transforms `process.env.SOME_VAR` type calls to the value of `SOME_VAR` during bundle time.

The only headache I had with it was that when I was first trying to see how it worked I was changing the environment variables, but it only seemed to work "randomly". Turns out I was a victim of `webpack`'s cache. If there are no changes in the code it is watching it won't update the bundle. I then learned I had to be aware of that

Comment: FYI 'transform-inline-environment-variables' doesn't work any more. See https://github.com/babel/minify/issues/687